# Excel VBA populate First Blank Row vs. First Row with empty Column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to select the first blank row to populate,

```
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\WFACS - Work Order System\Work Order Management System.xlsm")
Worksheets("Sheet5").Select
Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A3").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A2")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = TaskType
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = TimeSensitive
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = TimeSensitiveDate
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = TodaysDate
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Address
    .Offset(RowCount, 5) = Location
    .Offset(RowCount, 6) = Department
    .Offset(RowCount, 7) = ContactName
    .Offset(RowCount, 8) = ContactEmail
    .Offset(RowCount, 9) = Description
```

I would like to change it to populate the first row that has Column A empty using this code:

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

But every time I put it into the code I end up with a Run-time Error (9): Subscript out of range.

Can someone help me put these two together, I know there are other threads on here that talk about the issue, but nothing has helped me resolve this particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your worksheet has something in cells A1 and A2, then the following code should work:

```
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\WFACS - Work Order System\Work Order Management System.xlsm")
With myData.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    .Cells(1, "A").Value = TaskType
    .Cells(1, "B").Value = TimeSensitive
    .Cells(1, "C").Value = TimeSensitiveDate
    .Cells(1, "D").Value = TodaysDate
    .Cells(1, "E").Value = Address
    .Cells(1, "F").Value = Location
    .Cells(1, "G").Value = Department
    .Cells(1, "H").Value = ContactName
    .Cells(1, "I").Value = ContactEmail
    .Cells(1, "J").Value = Description
End With
```

That avoids any `Select` statements.

If you don't have any data in cell `A2`, then it would be better to use:

```
With myData.Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(myData.Worksheets("Sheet5").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
```

which works from the bottom and searches upwards to find the last used cell.  (But doesn't handle the case where there are empty cells above the last non-empty cell.)

---

Edit (for "advanced users"):

As A.S.H pointed out in a comment, this can be done by:

```
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\WFACS - Work Order System\Work Order Management System.xlsm")
myData.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 10).Value = Array( _
              TaskType, _
              TimeSensitive, _
              TimeSensitiveDate, _
              TodaysDate, _
              Address, _
              Location, _
              Department, _
              ContactName, _
              ContactEmail, _
              Description)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect that OP needs something like `.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`. But besides, why do you guys *hate* using arrays? :(

Comment: @A.S.H LOL - I was editing my answer as you were entering your comment.  (And I hate arrays because it is too hard to educate people to use "perfect" code if they are still struggling to understand the basics.)

Comment: Dont you like `.Cells(1, "A").Resize(,10).Value=Array(TaskType, TimeSensitive, etc, etc)`? Arrays not only it shorten code, but they also minimize the the Excel-VBA exchange ;)

Comment: @A.S.H - I like it, but one lesson a week is enough for most people posting questions.  Otherwise their brain explodes from information overload!  :D

Comment: @A.S.H - catch-22 - an advanced user wouldn't stumble across this question, therefore they wouldn't see the advanced answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm happier now :D